# "Saving" an OpenLayers session so that it can be restored

Tags: javascript, session, extjs, cookies, openlayers-3

I'm building a web interface which allows user to upload layers from GeoServer and perform spatial manipulations with the data. Therefore, the map consists of preloaded basemaps and data loaded by the user.

I want the user to be able to "save" his session, so that he can come back later and restore it. I'm planning on adding a login menu when the user enters the interface.

My interface is entirely built with ExtJS 6 and OpenLayers3.

Anyone have already done something similar and can give me a clue on how to save the session and restore it later ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done something similar with ExtJS6 and OL2.

I defined an Ext.panel.Panel that contains the OpenLayers Map (MapPanel).
MapPanel has is stateful:true, has a stateId and has some custom stateEvents (center, zoom and layer visibility).

Then just override that getState and setState functions of the MapPanel to save and restore map state.

You can use the extjs CookieProvider to store the states, or you can create a provider that save it to database or whatever..

On the OL size, register to map events (layer added, map moved, zoom changed) and reflect those changes to the MapPanel.

See the extjs docs for CookieProvider and stateful to know how to implement it.

Comment: Thank you! I think it's gonna be useful for me !